# Working around multicollinearity

Tags: anova, multicollinearity

Given that I am far from an expert statistician, perhaps the community can inform me if my first thought to work around multicollinearity is going to result in questionable results. I have a model with ~ 24 DVs and 6 IVs. Two of my IVs share a high (0.79) correlation. The result is that when my model includes all of these IVs, the results turn out insignificant. However, when I fracture my model into 6 different ones (one for each IV), I find significant results. Two questions here:

1. What is the highest level of correlation recommended to maintain an assumption of no multicollinearity?
2. Would dividing up my IVs like this be 'inappropriate'?

ps. Ive considered PLSR and Principle Component, but it would not make much sense with the IVs I am using.

Edit: here is my model.

```
model <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3, DV4, DV5,... DV20) ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + IV4 + IV5, data = MYDATA)
Manova(model)
```

Comment: How are you modeling your six response variables, some kind of multivariate regression or MANCOVA? (Multivariate regression has multiple response variables; multiple regression has multiple predictor variables. You have both.)

Comment: what's the purpose of regression? inference?

Comment: Dave - Is a multivariate multiple regression a better path forward? My response and predictor variables are both numerical. IVs are discrete falling between 0-100, DVs are in a variety of units but all discrete as well.

Comment: Aksakal - It is inference. I am trying to see which of the 6 IVs predict any of the IVs